# Can I call a stored procedure with hibernate criteria?

Tags: java, hibernate, stored-procedures, criteria

Can I use Hibernate criteria to call a stored procudure?

Comment: Hibernate also allows you to execute database calls directly. You could also do it that way.

Comment: Thanks fot your answer, but how can i do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See [Using stored procedures for querying](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/querysql.html#sp_query) in the reference documentation.

Mapped queries are called like this.

```
List employment = sess.getNamedQuery("BigSP")
    .list();
```

A mapped query can return entities.

```
<sql-query name="BigSP" callable="true">
    <return alias="emp" class="Employment">
        <return-property name="employee" column="EMPLOYEE"/>
        <return-property name="employer" column="EMPLOYER"/>
        <return-property name="startDate" column="STARTDATE"/>
        <return-property name="endDate" column="ENDDATE"/>
        <return-property name="regionCode" column="REGIONCODE"/>
        <return-property name="id" column="EID"/>
        <return-property name="salary">
            <return-column name="VALUE"/>
            <return-column name="CURRENCY"/>
        </return-property>
    </return>
    { call BigSP }
</sql-query>
```

Answer (score 5):

No, you need to use a native query. If you are using annotations, see [2.3.2. Mapping native queries](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/reference/en/html_single/#entity-mapping-query-native).

Below an example:

```
@Entity
@NamedNativeQuery(
    name="baz", 
    query="call fooProc(:bar, :i)", 
    callable=true, 
    readOnly=true, 
    resultClass=Foo.class
)
public class Foo {
    private Date when;
    //...
}
```

And to call it:

```
@Stateless
public class FooBean implements FooLocal {
    @PersistenceContext EntityManager em;

    public Foo getAFoo(string bar, int i) {
    Foo result = (Foo)em.createNamedQuery("baz").setParameter("bar", bar).setParameter("i", i).getSingleResult();
    return result;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks Thivent, but we dont use annoations :(

Comment: @Gaston Then refer to Lachlan's answer.

Answer (score 2):

[This document](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/querysql.html#sp_query) describes how to map the result of a stored procedure, executed as a native query.

You can't do it with the Criteria API, but this shouldn't matter.