# How can we call a stored procedure with Hibernate and JPA?

Tags: java, database, hibernate, stored-procedures, orm

How can we call a stored procedure using Hibernate or JPA?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I call a stored procedure with hibernate criteria?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2515690/can-i-call-a-stored-procedure-with-hibernate-criteria)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following

```
 Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
PreparedStatement st = session.connection().prepareStatement("{call procedureName(?, ?)}");
                st.setString(1, formatter.format(parameter1));
                st.setString(2, formatter.format(parameter2));
                st.execute();
tx.commit();
```

Please add the exception handling wherever required.

Comment: You are retrieving the connection from hibernate session and then using plain JDBC. This code is not taking advantage of Hibernate support.

Answer (score 25):

Considering the following stored procedure that simply returns a basic return value:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE count_comments (  
   postId IN NUMBER,  
   commentCount OUT NUMBER )  
AS 
BEGIN 
    SELECT COUNT(*) INTO commentCount  
    FROM post_comment  
    WHERE post_id = postId; 
END;
```

You can call this one with standard JPA:

```
StoredProcedureQuery query = entityManager
    .createStoredProcedureQuery("count_comments")
    .registerStoredProcedureParameter(1, Long.class, 
        ParameterMode.IN)
    .registerStoredProcedureParameter(2, Long.class, 
        ParameterMode.OUT)
    .setParameter(1, 1L);

query.execute();

Long commentCount = (Long) query.getOutputParameterValue(2);
```

If the stored procedure returns a SYS_REFCURSOR:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE post_comments ( 
   postId IN NUMBER, 
   postComments OUT SYS_REFCURSOR ) 
AS 
BEGIN
    OPEN postComments FOR
    SELECT *
    FROM post_comment 
    WHERE post_id = postId; 
END;
```

You can call it like this:

```
StoredProcedureQuery query = entityManager
    .createStoredProcedureQuery("post_comments")
    .registerStoredProcedureParameter(1, Long.class, 
         ParameterMode.IN)
    .registerStoredProcedureParameter(2, Class.class, 
         ParameterMode.REF_CURSOR)
    .setParameter(1, 1L);

query.execute();

List<Object[]> postComments = query.getResultList();
```

If you want to call an Oracle database function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fn_count_comments ( 
    postId IN NUMBER ) 
    RETURN NUMBER 
IS
    commentCount NUMBER; 
BEGIN
    SELECT COUNT(*) INTO commentCount 
    FROM post_comment 
    WHERE post_id = postId; 
    RETURN( commentCount ); 
END;
```

You can't use the `StoredProcedureQuery` since it does not work with Hibernate 5, so you can call it like this:

```
BigDecimal commentCount = (BigDecimal) entityManager
    .createNativeQuery(
        "SELECT fn_count_comments(:postId) FROM DUAL"
    )
    .setParameter("postId", 1L)
    .getSingleResult();
```

or with plain JDBC:

```
Session session = entityManager.unwrap( Session.class ); 

Integer commentCount = session.doReturningWork( connection -> {
    try (CallableStatement function = connection.prepareCall(
            "{ ? = call fn_count_comments(?) }" )) {
        function.registerOutParameter( 1, Types.INTEGER );
        function.setInt( 2, 1 );
        function.execute();
        return function.getInt( 1 );
    }
} );
```

For more details check out the following articles:

- [How to call Oracle stored procedures and functions with JPA and Hibernate](https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-call-oracle-stored-procedures-and-functions-from-hibernate/)
- [How to call SQL Server stored procedures and functions with JPA and Hibernate](https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-call-sql-server-stored-procedures-and-functions-from-hibernate/)
- [How to call PostgreSQL functions (stored procedures) with JPA and Hibernate](https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-call-postgresql-functions-from-hibernate/)
- [How to call MySQL stored procedures and functions with JPA and Hibernate](https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-call-mysql-stored-procedures-and-functions-with-jpa-and-hibernate/)

Comment: Notice that JPA 2.1 has `EntityManager.createStoredProcedureQuery` method and it will not resolve if JPA 2.0 was in your classpath https://stackoverflow.com/a/34174204/402488

Answer (score 2):

To execute remote procedure use this construction:

**Mapping**

```
<sql-query name="RP">   
    {call some_rp(:param1, :param2)}
</sql-query>
```

**Java code**

```
session.getNamedQuery("RP").setInteger("param1", 1).setInteger("param2", 2).executeUpdate();
```

Comment: Is this method compatible for both RDBMs (Oracle and Sql Server) ?

Answer (score 1):

One way to call the stored procedure from hibernate

Declare your store procedure inside the `@NamedNativeQueries` annotation

```
//Stock.java

@NamedNativeQueries({
    @NamedNativeQuery(
    name = "callStockStoreProcedure",
    query = "CALL GetStocks(:stockCode)",
    resultClass = Stock.class
    )
})
@Entity
@Table(name = "stock")
public class Stock implements java.io.Serializable {

// Call it with getNamedQuery().

Query query = session.getNamedQuery("callStockStoreProcedure")
    .setParameter("stockCode", "7277");
List result = query.list();
for(int i=0; i<result.size(); i++){
    Stock stock = (Stock)result.get(i);
    System.out.println(stock.getStockCode());
}
```

This works

Answer (score 0):

Here is the complete Solution to call a Stored Procedure with Just IN parameters ---

1) Create the Stored Procedure to act on a Table or a Set of Tables:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE procedure insertHouseHello (
house_date in timestamp,
house_name in varchar2,
house_number in number,
house_value in float) 
is
begin
 insert into House("HOUSE_DATE","HOUSE_NAME","HOUSE_NUMBER","HOUSE_VALUE")
 values ( house_date, house_name,house_number,house_value);
 commit;
 end;
```

2) Execute the Stored Procedure from SQL Prompt to check the input. When You call the procedure from Java/Hibernate also You should see the similar result:

```
exec insertHouseHello(sysdate,'one',123,104);
```

3) In the Java Code:

```
log.info("Now trying to call the Stored Procedure*****************");
Query exQuery = session.createSQLQuery("CALL " +
        "insertHouseHello(:timestmp,:hname,:hno,:hvalue)");
exQuery.setParameter("timestmp", 
        new java.sql.Timestamp(Calendar.getInstance().getTime().getTime()));
exQuery.setParameter("hname", 34);
exQuery.setParameter("hno", 212);
exQuery.setParameter("hvalue", 12);
int exRows = exQuery.executeUpdate();
log.info("Executed Rows from Stored Procedure****************"+exRows);
```

4) Now check the result in the Table, that should get updated accordingly:

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate provides support for queries via stored procedures and functions. Say for example if we have the following stored procedure,

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION selectAllEmployments
RETURN SYS_REFCURSOR
AS
    st_cursor SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN
    OPEN st_cursor FOR
 SELECT EMPLOYEE, EMPLOYER,
 STARTDATE, ENDDATE,
 REGIONCODE, EID, VALUE, CURRENCY
 FROM EMPLOYMENT;
      RETURN  st_cursor;
 END;
```

Which return the list of all employees. The stored procedure/function must return a resultset as the first out-parameter to be able to work with Hibernate.

To use the above query in Hibernate you need to map it via a named query.

```
<sql-query name="selectAllEmployees_SP" callable="true">
    <return alias="emp" class="Employment">
        <return-property name="employee" column="EMPLOYEE"/>
        <return-property name="employer" column="EMPLOYER"/>
        <return-property name="startDate" column="STARTDATE"/>
        <return-property name="endDate" column="ENDDATE"/>
        <return-property name="regionCode" column="REGIONCODE"/>
        <return-property name="id" column="EID"/>
        <return-property name="salary">
            <return-column name="VALUE"/>
            <return-column name="CURRENCY"/>
        </return-property>
    </return>
    { ? = call selectAllEmployments() }
</sql-query>
```

***Rules/limitations for using stored procedures:***

- Stored procedure queries cannot be paged with setFirstResult()/setMaxResults().
- The recommended call form is standard SQL92: `{ ? = call functionName(<parameters>) }` or `{ ? = call procedureName(<parameters>}`. Native call syntax is not supported.

*`For Oracle the following rules apply:`*

- A function must return a result set.
- The first parameter of a procedure must be an OUT that returns a result set. This is done by using a SYS_REFCURSOR type in Oracle 9 or 10. In Oracle you need to define a REF CURSOR type. See Oracle literature for further information.

*`For Sybase or MS SQL server the following rules apply:`*

- The procedure must return a result set. Note that since these servers can return multiple result sets and update counts, Hibernate will iterate the results and take the first result that is a result set as its return value. Everything else will be discarded.
- If you can enable SET NOCOUNT ON in your procedure it will probably be more efficient, but this is not a requirement.

[Source Ref.: From the official Hibernate docuementation.](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/4.0/manual/en-US/html_single/#sp_query)

Answer (score 0):

one approach can be with getNamedQuery().

```
Query query = session.getNamedQuery("callStockStoreProcedure")
    .setParameter("stockCode", "7277");
List result = query.list();
for(int i=0; i<result.size(); i++){
    Stock stock = (Stock)result.get(i);
    System.out.println(stock.getStockCode());
}
```

you have to map or use annotations

there are others: [source](http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/how-to-call-store-procedure-in-hibernate/)

Answer (score 0):

This easy and smart way to call procedure :

```
 @Query(value = "call SCHEMA.PROCEDURE_NAME()" , nativeQuery = true)
```

and if your procedure contain parameters you can call it like below:

```
@Transactional
@Modifying
@Query(value = "call SCHEMA.PROCEDURE_NAME(:param1 , :param2)" , nativeQuery = true)
void validateUpdatePaymentStatus(@Param("param1") String param1, @Param("param2") int param2);
```

and if your procedure contain update, insert or delete use

```
@Transactional
@Modifying
```