# How to get OUTPUT value from stored procedure in hibernate (SQL SERVER)

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate, stored-procedures

I have stored procedure in `MS SQL Server`

```
CREATE PROC dbo.insertData 
    @param1 nvarchar(11),
    @param2 nvarchar(30),
    @ID bigint OUTPUT
AS 
BEGIN   
    INSERT INTO dbo.Adaptor (Col1, Col2) VALUES (@param1, @param2)
    SET @ID = SCOPE_IDENTITY(); 
END
```

And I want to get this generated ID as output parameter in java.

I have created a mapping file

```
<sql-query name="insertData" callable="true">
    <return alias="adaptor" class="MyClass">
        <return-property name="id" column="ID" />
    </return>
    { ? = call InsertData(:param1, :param2) }
</sql-query>
```

and trying to execute it from java

```
  Query query = entityManager.createNamedQuery("insertData");

            query.setParameter("param1", object);
            query.setParameter("param2", getName());
            // TODO try to use getSingleResult in tests
            List result = query.getResultList();
```

But I have exception java.sql.SQLException: Parameter #3 has not been set

If I remove ? = I got

java.sql.SQLException: Procedure or function 'insertData' expects parameter '@ID', which was not supplied.

Has anyone any idea how code/mapping file should look like? Thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [call Stored Procedure in hibernate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4524841/call-stored-procedure-in-hibernate)

Comment: No, I have problem to get value of a filed that is OUTPUT in sproc. How to exec sproc I showed in my question

Answer (score 4):

```
Query query = session.createSQLQuery(
    "CALL GetStocks(:stockCode)")
    .addEntity(Stock.class)
    .setParameter("stockCode", "7277");

List result = query.list();
for(int i=0; i<result.size(); i++){
    Stock stock = (Stock)result.get(i);
    System.out.println(stock.getStockCode());
}
```

[from here](http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/how-to-call-store-procedure-in-hibernate/)

Comment: 1) I don't have session object. entityManager only.
2) In my case insert statement is executed. Also I have one more parameter which in sql server is marked input/output. And I don't know how to handle it

Comment: createSQlQuery just allows you to run a native sql ... the returned value wil lbe handled the same way