# createStoredProcedureQuery is not resolved

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, stored-procedures, dns

here is my code and createStoredProcedureQuery has redline underneath in eclipse, and not resolved, I tried many ways still could not get what is wrong.

```
private static EntityManagerFactory factory;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("mypersistenceUnit");
    EntityManager em = factory.createEntityManager();

    // Create call stored procedure
    em.getTransaction().begin();
    StoredProcedureQuery storedProcedure = em.**createStoredProcedureQuery**("getCode");
    // set parameters
    storedProcedure.registerStoredProcedureParameter("name", String.class, ParameterMode.IN);
    storedProcedure.registerStoredProcedureParameter("num", String.class, ParameterMode.IN);
    storedProcedure.registerStoredProcedureParameter("code", String.class, ParameterMode.OUT);

    // execute SP
    storedProcedure.execute();
    // get result
    String code= (String)storedProcedure.getOutputParameterValue("code");
    System.out.println("code is: " + code);
    em.getTransaction().commit();
    em.close();
}
```

Comment: StoredProcedureQuery storedProcedure = em.**createStoredProcedureQuery**("getCode"); Are you the ** part of your actual code or you were just depicting it for the eclipse

Comment: Do you have all the necessary jars ( like hibernate-entitymanager.jar) in your classpath, if not you may get those wavy lines in em.getTransaction() as well. @user1765427

Comment: ** are I tried to make it bold, not part of code, I do have hibernate-entitymanager.jar on classpath have following: hibernate-entitymanager.jar, hibernate-ejb3-persistence, hibernate-annotations, hibernate-core, hibernate-eh-cache, hibernate-jpa-2.0.-api,1.0.0.Final, hib-oscache,proxool

Comment: Try build it and see if it complains of any compilation error ? also in the try exit and come back to eclipse

Comment: yes it gives me compilation error while doing build: symbol: method createStoredProcedureQuery(String) location: variable em of type EntityManager, exiting eclipse did not help.

Comment: Mostly older version of hibernate and  jpa in classpath.

Answer (score 1):

you need declare and set parameter:

```
/*Declare parameters*/

storedProcedure.registerStoredProcedureParameter( "name",       String.class,ParameterMode.IN);
storedProcedure.registerStoredProcedureParameter( "num",        String.class,ParameterMode.IN);
storedProcedure.registerStoredProcedureParameter("code", String.class, ParameterMode.OUT);



/*set parameter value*/
 storedProcedure.setParameter("name", "value_name");
 storedProcedure.setParameter("num", "value_num");
 storedProcedure.execute();
 // get result
 String code= (String)storedProcedure.getOutputParameterValue("code");
```

--remember, the parameters name in the store procedure must be the same to declared

Answer (score 0):

JPA 2.1 is what provides that method. If you don't include the JPA API 2.1 jar in your CLASSPATH (and instead use JPA API 2.0) then you will get that. Fix your JPA API jar version (remove JPA API 2.0 and include JPA API 2.1)