# Can not execute stored procedure JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

While attempting to execute a stored procedure in Oracle using JPA, I'm getting the following exception:

> Caused by: org.switchyard.HandlerException:
>   java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   javax.persistence.EntityManager.createStoredProcedureQuery(Ljava/lang/String;)
>   Ljavax/persistence/StoredProcedureQuery;

There is a code snippet:

```
query = enmanager.createStoredProcedureQuery("BEGIN YLABPACK.ejemplo(?,?);END;")
    .registerStoredProcedureParameter(1, String.class, ParameterMode.IN)
    .registerStoredProcedureParameter(2, String.class, ParameterMode.IN)
    .setParameter(1, datosIdController.getSerie())
    .setParameter(2, respuesta).execute();
```

Comment: as I can execute a stored procedure using the following

Comment: EntityManagerFactory enfactory =      Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("SGR_BDD_4");
  EntityManager enmanager = enfactory.createEntityManager();

Comment: Dup of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34170256/createstoredprocedurequery-is-not-resolved

Comment: You also do NOT define the text for the stored procedure in createStoredProcedureQuery ... just call the name of the StoredProcedure which is already in the datastore, as per http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_4_2/jpa/stored_procedures.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method **EntityManager#createStoredProcedureQuery(Ljava/lang/String;)** is available since Java Persistence 2.1. Check the JPA version you have. Mind that it can be a dependency conflict (i.e. due to maven transitive dependency). If you can share more about your project setup it will be easier to help you.

Comment: change the version 2.1 but I skip the following error

Comment: Cannot find the declaration of element 'persistence'

Comment: @WilliamMorales what do you mean by skip the following error? Could you please provide a stack trace? Also, please don't forget to accept my answer in case it answers your question.