# How invoke a Store Procedure using Hibernate con Sql Server 2000?

Tags: java, sql-server, spring, hibernate

I have a problem calling store procedure using hibernate session:

Code Java:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
@Override
public List<Map<String, Object>> buscarCierre(String vanio) throws Exception {
    try {
        List<Map<String, Object>> mapa = new ArrayList<>();
        String queryString = "usp_Cierre_Dia_Obtener_CierrePorAnio :anio, :pagActual, :tamanio";
        Query query = super.getSession().createSQLQuery(queryString);
        query.setString("anio", vanio);
        query.setInteger("pagActual", 1);
        query.setInteger("tamanio", 1);
        List<Object[]> result = query.list(); // requires casting for generics
        for(Object[] obj : result) {
            System.out.println("--- "+obj[0]);
            System.out.println("*** "+obj[1]);
        }


        return mapa;
    } catch (Exception e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

        throw new Exception( getGenerarError(Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[1].getMethodName(), 
                             Constantes.NIVEL_APP_DAO,
                             this.getClass().getName(),
                             e.getMessage()) );
    } 
}
```

It invoking from SQL Server 2000, is this: `usp_Cierre_Dia_Obtener_CierrePorAnio '2014',1,1`

Please could help me, and finally also to check if I'm getting the data correctly through a `List <Object []>`

Error:

```
Hibernate: usp_Cierre_Dia_Obtener_CierrePorAnio ?, ?, ?
WARN : org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - SQL Error: 170, SQLState: 37000
ERROR: org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - Line 1: Incorrect syntax near 'usp_Cierre_Dia_Obtener_CierrePorAnio'.
org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:122)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:49)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:125)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:110)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:61)
```

Comment: This is likely because Hibernate sends a bunch of other crap before your command, and only when it is the first statement in a batch is a stored procedure allowed to be executed without the, well, EXECUTE. As a first step, try `String queryString = "EXEC dbo.usp_Cierre_Dia_...` but surely there is a way to send this as a stored procedure and not a queryString. Also [please always use the schema prefix when creating or referencing objects](https://sqlblog.org/2019/09/12/bad-habits-to-kick-avoiding-the-schema-prefix).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query string you are using is not correct so Hibernate generated invalid command like : `Hibernate: usp_Cierre_Dia_Obtener_CierrePorAnio ?, ?, ?`

Refer to [Hibernate document](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/querysql.html#sp_query) to know how to call stored procedures using hibernate

Also there are other examples in SO that shows how we can call stored procedures in Hibernate for example:

[Can I call a stored procedure with hibernate criteria?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2515690/can-i-call-a-stored-procedure-with-hibernate-criteria)

[How can we call a stored procedure with Hibernate and JPA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4524841/call-stored-procedure-in-hibernate)

Answer (score 1):

you can map a stored procedure to a bean and also don't forget quotes around string argument:

```
Query query = session.createSQLQuery("EXEC usp_Cierre_Dia_Obtener_CierrePorAnio :anio, :pagActual, :tamanio").addEntity(<MappedClass>.class);
query.setString("anio", "vanio");
query.setInteger("pagActual", 1);
query.setInteger("tamanio", 1);
List<MappedClass> list = query.list();
```